# jQuery basic slider keeps going right

Tags: jquery, slider

When you check the following site:

[slider example](http://www.grafisign.nl/CAKE/simple/news/index.php)

When you click the button << 'left' everyting works fine.
But when you click right the slider content dissapears when it is at the end instead of going back to the first slide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to close a tag at line 104 (the a tag).