# Convert a PHP "Object" to a SESSION?

Tags: php

I have a {$obj->product_stock} which contains a numeric value - the stock of the product.

How can I convert that {$obj->product_stock} to a SESSION? Here is what I tried...

```
$_SESSION['product_stock'] = {$obj->product_stock};
```

Why does it error and how can I get round this?

```
<?php
    session_start();
    include_once("config.php");

    // Current URL of the Page. cart_update.php redirects back to this URL
    $current_url = urlencode($url="http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="keywords" content="">
    <title>Product Page</title>
    <?php include("includes/header-includes.php"); ?>
</head>
<body>

<?php include("includes/navigation.php"); ?>
<?php include("includes/basket-warning.php"); ?>

<!-- Products List Start -->
<?php
$ProductID = intval($_REQUEST['ProductID']);
$results = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM products where ProductID = '$ProductID';");

if($results) {
    $_SESSION['product_stock'] = $obj->product_stock;
    echo "STOCK: ". $_SESSION['product_stock'] ."";

    $products_item = '<ul class="products">';
    // Fetch results, set as object and output HTML
    while($obj = $results->fetch_object()) {
        $products_item .= <<< EOT
        <li class="product">
            <form method="post" action="cart_update.php">
                <div class="product-content">
                    <h3>{$obj->ProductName} <strong>(STOCK: {$obj->product_stock}</strong>)</h3>

                    <div class="product-image" style="background: url({$obj->TypeImage}) no-repeat; background-size: 100%; min-height: 551.328px;">
                        <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                            <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
                                <div class="item active"><img src={$obj->TypeImage} class="img-responsive"></div>
                                <div class="item"><img src={$obj->AlternativeImagesOne} class="img-responsive"></div>
                                <div class="item"><img src={$obj->AlternativeImagesTwo} class="img-responsive"></div>
                                <div class="item"><img src={$obj->AlternativeImagesThree} class="img-responsive"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="product-content-cont">
                        <h4>{$obj->ProductName} - Overview</h4>
                        <p>{$obj->ProductDescription}</p>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="like-what-you-see">
                    <fieldset>
                        <label>
                            <span>Price</span>
                            {$currency}{$obj->Price}
                        </label>

                        <label>
                            <input type="" size="1" maxlength="2" name="product_qty" value="1" class="form-control" />
                        </label>
                    </fieldset>

                    <input type="hidden" name="ProductCode" value="{$obj->ProductCode}" />
                    <input type="hidden" name="type" value="add" />
                    <input type="hidden" name="return_url" value="{$current_url}" />
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning">Add</button>  
                </div>
            </form>
        </li>
EOT;
}

    $products_item .= '</ul>';

    echo $products_item;
}
?>    
<!-- Products List End -->

<?php include("includes/footer.php"); ?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try to remove the brackets `{` `}`

Comment: First try. I think its work

Comment: I have removed the brackets and it still does not work.

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: There is no error message. The SESSION just evaluates to blank.

Comment: what is the result of `var_dump($obj->product_stock);`

Comment: I have uploaded the whole code for you guys.

Comment: var_dump($obj->product_stock); is NULL.

Comment: Then that is your problem. the variable `$obj->product_stock` has no value. What should be in the variable?

Comment: However, if you look at the code: <h3>{$obj->ProductName} <strong>(STOCK: {$obj->product_stock}</strong>)</h3> shows the value 480 which is in the database...

Comment: It does have a value though, it's writing it out at the (STOCK: part of the page.

Comment: Ah, I see now. Creating an answer for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code:

`$_SESSION['product_stock'] = $obj->product_stock;
    echo "STOCK: ". $_SESSION['product_stock'] ."";`

is outside the while loop. Therefore `$obj`  is not yet defined.

Move the code above into the while loop like this

```
$products_item = '<ul class="products">';
// Fetch results, set as object and output HTML
while($obj = $results->fetch_object()) {
    $_SESSION['product_stock'] = $obj->product_stock;
    echo "STOCK: ". $_SESSION['product_stock'] ."";
    ....
```

Comment: I am such an idiot... I totally forgot about the while loop. :( Thank you so much.

Comment: no problem, we where all idiots once ;) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13797021/jquery-basic-slider-keeps-going-right